# X Close Button in QToolButton

Tags: c++, qt

How can I display an X close button in the top right corner of subclassed QToolButton, and control its the behavior?

Comment: I don't know much about Qt, but does this help: http://stackoverflow.com/q/459372/365102 ?

Comment: Saw this one, very different widget type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Subclass QToolButton and in constructor of your class e.g. MyToolButton add a child QPushButton on top of your tool button.

Comment: How does one add a widget to another widget? There is no addWidget() member available for QToolButton.

Comment: By specifiyng QToolButton as a parent widget. Or using a layout for QToolButton and adding your widget to the layout.